# Trying to define a function that adds an element to the top of an existing array

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

I am learning javascript and need to define a function that will add an element to the top of an array(two parameters array and element). I have the array created, but when I code out how I think the function should look I get the number 5 instead of the element I insert being added to the top of the array. Below is the code I have, can you help me out with why it doesn't work? I expect it to return the array with the new element at the top instead it just returns the number 5.

```
var chocolateBars = [
  'snickers',  
  'hundred grand', 
  'kitkat', 
  'skittles'
]
 function addElementToBeginningOfArray(array, element) {
   return array.unshift(element)}

  addElementToBeginningOfArray(chocolateBars, 'twix')
```

Comment: Unshift returns the length of the new array

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/unshift, The unshift() method adds one or more elements to the beginning of an array and returns the new length of the array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unshift returns the length of the array. You should return the array on a separate line:

```js
var chocolateBars = [
  'snickers',  
  'hundred grand', 
  'kitkat', 
  'skittles'
]
 
function addElementToBeginningOfArray(array, element) {
   array.unshift(element)
   return array
}

// Returns array with new element
console.log(addElementToBeginningOfArray(chocolateBars, 'twix'))

// The original is now modified too
console.log(chocolateBars)
```

Note, however, that this function will edit the original array. To avoid this, you could create a shallow copy of the original, and insert the new element right away:

```js
var chocolateBars = [
  'snickers',  
  'hundred grand', 
  'kitkat', 
  'skittles'
]
 
function addElementToBeginningOfArray(array, element) {
   return [element, ...array]
}

// Returns new array with added element
console.log(addElementToBeginningOfArray(chocolateBars, 'twix'))

// Original is not modified
console.log(chocolateBars)
```

A nice, modern solution could be written in one line:

```js
var chocolateBars = [
  'snickers',  
  'hundred grand', 
  'kitkat', 
  'skittles'
]
 
const addElementToBeginningOfArray = (a, e) => [e, ...a]

console.log(addElementToBeginningOfArray(chocolateBars, 'twix'))
```